# Open new tab each time the button is clicked is not working in Edge browser

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge

I am trying to open link in new tab each time the button is clicked. It works fine in rest of the browsers but Edge. In edge, it will just refresh the previously opened new tab and thats all. 
To detect the Edge browser, I am doing the following:

```
if (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("trident") === -1) {
            window.oldUIWin = window.open(newUrl, winTitle);
        } 

a.menu-item(onclick="window.openOldUI(); return false;")
```

Is there something that I am doing wrong? Even if it can focus on the previously opened new tab that would do too. But window.focus() works only in Google Chrome. 
Any kind of help would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that Edge browser considers only "_blank" as the parameter for window.open and not anything else. So when i added this :

```
window.oldUIWin = window.open(newUrl, "_blank");
```

It worked fine. Weird but true !